# Permissão para alterar apenas uma coluna da tabela no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

boa noite!

Estou usando o PostgreSQL e nele tenho uma tabela chamda Produtos. Quando o usuário visita um produto pelo site dou um UPDATE nessa tabela para incrementar a coluna visitas.

O problema é que o usuário do banco de dados só pode ter permissão de leitura. Por isso gostaria de saber como faço para dar permissão de UPDATE apenas na coluna visitas da tabela produto. Se não for possível existe alguma alternativa?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui aqui galera!

A sintaxe ficou assim

```html
GRANT UPDATE(visitas) on produtos to user_website;
```

Ou seja

```html
GRANT UPDATE(coluna) on tabela to nome_usuario;
```